# Скрипт замены ссылки - нажатием на чекбокс

Tags: javascript

Всем привет

Есть 2 кнопки/ссылки, в виде картинок. Ссылки различаются только тем, что открывают в соседнем окне страницу с разными адресами (последняя цифра в адресе)

Можете ли подсказать JS скрипт, который бы позволил установить 1 кнопку/ссылку, и рядом с ней checkbox (изначально пустой),  и если нажимаем чекбокс - 1я кнопка/ссылка меняется на вторую, отжимаем чекбокс - обратно меняется на первую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

особенности браузеров заставляют в этому случае код яваскрипта писать в конце страницы. вот это будет работать.

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange="changeButton(this.checked);">
<a id="1" href="index.php?f=1"><img src="img/key.gif"></a>
<script>
function changeButton(checked) {
    if (checked === true) {
        document.getElementById('1').href = 'index.php?f=2';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('1').href = 'index.php?f=1';
    }
    alert(document.getElementById('1').href);
}
    ​</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: мне всегда казалось ,что их вообще в хеде нужно писать...

Comment: так все и оказалось. спасибо.

Comment: @metalurgus вообще да, но там есть нюансы, на разных браузерах оно по разному запускается... очень много с этим мучался. ушел на jquery - забыл про эти проблемы, да и про многие другие ;)

Comment: @metalurgus вообщем факт остается фактом =) напиши это до чекбокса -- не будет работать, напиши после -- будет работать.

Answer (score 1):

у чекбокса onChange="changeButton(this.checked)"
и описывает функцию

```
function changeButton(checked){
    if(checked == true){
        document.GetElementById('тут йади вашей кнопки-ссылки').href = 'ваша ссылка          если чекбокс отмечен';
   }else{
        document.GetElementById('тут йади вашей кнопки-ссылки').href = 'ваша ссылка          если чекбокс не отмечен';
   }
}
```

Comment: рядом с кнопкой поместил checkbox, у него прописал onChange. прописал скрипт. назначил ссылке id, как и в скрипте - не сработало

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeButton(checked){
    if(checked == true){
        document.GetElementById('1').href = 'index.php?f=2';
    } else{
        document.GetElementById('1').href = 'index.php?f=1';
    }
    </script><!--check/un-->
    <input type="checkbox" onChange="changeButton(this.checked)">
    <a id="1" href="index.php?f=1"><img src="img/key.gif"></a>

Comment: забыл закрыть блок функции. перед </script> нужно добавить }

И еще GetElementById с маленькой буквы.